# how to uniformly select rows in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am new to here and please let me know if I didn't make the question clearly.

If I have a m rows in a table and I want to select n rows uniformly. In other words, the interval between first row and next row is m / n.

For example, if i have a 10 rows and I want to select 5 rows out of them, then the selected rows would be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 because the interval is 10 / 5 = 2.

Does anyone can help?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? There are a number of ways of doing this

Comment: I am using SQL server management studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [row_number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186734.aspx) and the [modulo operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190279.aspx)

Tables don't have any inherent order. You need to define an ordering expression (e.g column names) to define what "first" and "next" mean.

```
DECLARE @StepSize int = 2;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourOrderingColumn) AS RN
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN % @StepSize = 1;
```

Comment: thanks but i am not selecting the odd number rows. if the step size is 3 then I will select 1, 4, 7 etc.

Comment: So change `%2` to `%3` in that case.

Comment: one more question

Comment: why declare @tot = select count(*) from table; does not work? I want to calculate the total number of rows in the table

Comment: Because it's not valid syntax. `declare @tot int = ( select count(*) from table);` is correct.

Comment: oh, great, thanks a lot. save me a lot of time

Comment: martin one more question.

Comment: with cte as
(
 select *, Row_Number() over (order by time) as rn
 from table
)

declare @a := select count(\*) from cte;

Comment: why this is wrong? I am trying to find the row number of selected columns